# Can I run VirtualBox and VMWare Fusion on the same machine?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-fusion

I have both VirtualBox and VMWare VMs on separate laptops.

Can I run both of those VMWare Fusion and VirtualBox on my Macbook Pro, assuming that I don't want to run them at the same time?

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you can't run both on the same machine. I would not recommend that you run both at the same time since they might fight for access to the processor cores.

Comment: Justin: as they tend to interact quite heavily with the available hardware, one might see a scenario where their drivers conflict with each other even when they are not running at the same time. Shouldn't happen, you're right; but still.